# jQuery click() fails with "Could not convert JavaScript argument"

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click

Here's the setup: A user fills out a certain form on my page, which is submitted via AJAX (jQuery `$.post`). In the return function I add an element to the page related to the form that was submitted. This element has a `click()` handler attached to it. The element goes on the page without issue, but when I click it, I get the dreaded "Could not convert JavaScript argument". Here is the line that adds the element to the page:

```
$('<span class="appointment" id="a'+aid+'">'
    +type+name+'</span>').click(appointmentDetails).appendTo(calSlot);
```

Again, this is being called inside the success callback of the jQuery `post` function. The `appointmentDetails` function exists, as do all the variables. I also tried like this:

```
var newHTML='<span class="appointment" id="a'+aid+'">'+type+name+'</span>';
$(calSlot).append(newHTML);
$("#a"+aid).click(appointmentDetails);
```

The `appointmentDetails` function uses either a passed ID or `this.id` to get the appointment ID, then runs a jQuery `.post` to get and display the appointment details. Here are the basics:

```
function appointmentDetails(appID) {
    if (!appID) var appID=$(this).attr("id").substr(1);
    $.post("data/appointments.php", {aid: appID, action: "details"}, function(data) {
        //Callback stuff. Doubtful it's relevant
    }, "xml");
}
```

Comment: What does the click handler (`appointmentDetails`) look like?

Comment: You want the full code? I gave a general idea at the end, but I can post it if necessary.

Comment: I don't think the code you've posted contains the problem. A simple event handler doesn't fail: http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/6/

Comment: Edited to include basic version of `appointmentDetails`

Comment: `appointmentDetails` will always receive one argument, the click event, not an `appID`.

Comment: @D.Strout: what is calSlot?

Comment: @HoàngLong The ID of a calendar slot in the form `day[day of month]-[time]`. As I said, though, the element is added successfully, so that doesn't really have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function appointmentDetails(appID) <--
```

appID would be a jQuery event object!

It is not undefined/false like you are expecting. You need to check if it is an object/string if you are overloading this function.

Comment: Another one of my `duh` moments. Ah well, makes sense; hopefully this will help other people out of **duh** moments. Thanks.